# Configurar favicon do meu site

Tags: html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu mudo esse ícone para usar o favicon do meu site?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ícone do site no Atalho ao adicionar site para a tela do celular na opção que o chrome tem Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304704/%c3%8dcone-do-site-no-atalho-ao-adicionar-site-para-a-tela-do-celular-na-op%c3%a7%c3%a3o-que-o)

Comment: Aqui tem sua resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304704/%C3%8Dcone-do-site-no-atalho-ao-adicionar-site-para-a-tela-do-celular-na-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-que-o/304708#304708

Answer (score 2):

- Primeiro recorte a imagem em editor de imagem de sua preferência;
- Salve a imagem recortada no formato .ico (um tamanho que uso é 34x34 pixels);
- Adicione esse código entre as tags < header >  < /header > no seu html:

  < header >

  < link rel="shortcut icon" href="pastaDaImg/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" / >

  < /header >

Lembre de colocar o caminho correto de onde está sua imagem ali no caminho href=""