# Definir o favicon do site (Flask)

Tags: html, python, flask

Eu quero saber como que coloca o ícone do site, eu tenho o ícone guardado em `static / favicon.ico`, mas na template quando tento referenciar, n dá em nada, é como se o código n existisse, já tentei tudo da [documentação do flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/favicon/) mas não dá em nada (nenhum erro no console do navegador nem no python)

edit: já tentei deixar no mesmo arquivo do template e do .py, nada foi

Comment: Olha se isso responde sua pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304704/%C3%8Dcone-do-site-no-atalho-ao-adicionar-site-para-a-tela-do-celular-na-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-que-o/304708#304708

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve pôr a tag no seu html para defini-lo, se o seu ícone é servido como arquivo estático pelo Flask, dentro da tag `<head>` seria mais ou menos o seguinte:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}"/>
```

Caso não resolva, tente reiniciar o serviço ou remover o cache da página do seu navegador.

Comment: já tentei isso, mas não funcionou

Comment: Estranho, fiz o exemplo acima em um teste antes de postar e funcionou. Qual a versão do flask está utilizando? Você limpou o cache do navegador/reiniciou o seu serviço flask como recomendado?

Comment: a versão é 1.0.3, e sim

Comment: Seu flask está rodando em modo debug? Se não tem certeza, tente rodar `export FLASK_ENV=development` (se estiver no windows, troque `export` por `set`) e depois, `flask run` para iniciar o serviço. Talvez isso ajude você a ver alguma mensagem de erro, que esteja impedindo a execução de sua rotina. Sem contar que o "hot reload" do seu serviço Flask sempre que houver mudanças no seu código só estará ativo no modo debug.

Comment: Não apareceu nada, só apareceu isso: `127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2019 18:54:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: deixa, funcionou, era o opera

Comment: Haha, ia dizer pra testar em outros navegadores. Bom que resolveu.